# pgadmin 4 won't quit on Macbook Pro

Tags: postgresql

I need to restart my Macbook Pro for a new OS update. Somehow the pgAdmin 4 won't quit even I try to quit it from its menu multiple times. Is another way to quit it?

Comment: I assume "pgAdmin 4" is a program? Then yes: open "activity monitor", find the program, select it in the search results and hit the x in the top left menu bar (not the red small x to close the program window of activity monitor, but the grey/white one). Then hit "force quit".

Comment: Yes, it is an app. I later learn to hold the option key and select "force to quit".

Comment: Do you have the elephant icon (same as the application icon) in your menu bar at the top of your screen ? If so, right-click on it and select 'Shut down server'

Comment: After few research I found out that it is a know issue in version 5.2, if you're still using this version please update your pgadmin4 to try quitting your app correctly !

Comment: @tama The pdadmin is a client. Thanks for the information. It is version 5.2. I will upgrade it.